# Almacenar documentos (jpg, pdf, doc, xls, etc) en base de datos DJango

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Hola**

Quiero almacenar documentos en la base de datos usando DJango, algún plugin o método que me permita convertir una imagen o documento a binario para almacenarlo en un campo de texto en una base de datos y que después pueda ser descifrado para visualizarlo nuevamente.

Comment: Recomendación. No lo hagas. Guarda tu archivo en una carpeta al subirlo y en la BBDD guardas la ruta de ese archivo.

Comment: @Jakala actualmente lo estoy haciendo así pero me surgía la duda de si es mas eficiente almacenarlo en la base de datos, ¿Porqué no es recomendable hacer esto?

Comment: Guardar en la BD implica pasar el archivo a  binario para guardarlo  y luego volver a armar el archivo para descargarlo o lo que haga falta  y esto tiene un alto coste computacional

Comment: Supon que guardas imágenes. Desde negocio te dicen que ciertas imágenes deben cambiar de tamaño(ej, imágenes de antes del 2017) no hay operaciones SQL para actualizar esto. Tienes que sacar esa imagen, cambiarla y volver a insertarla... el tiempo de acceso a BBDD se te puede disparar... Más fácil hacer un proceso sobre tu directorio donde tengas las imágenes...